# geth expect script not working

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running test contracts on the Ethereum testnet using geth. I need to make a file similar to a batch script which can execute commands one by one all in one go hence I am using expect to do so.

I keep getting the error: **"extra characters after close-brace while executing"** whilst running the script which is strange as I have removed the inner "" and converted them into ''.

Below is my incomplete expect script, any suggestions for friendlier alternatives to do doing this would be great.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/geth --testnet console
expect ">"
send     "personal.unlockAccount('0xdc85a8429998bd4eef79307e556f70bb70d8caf1','bitc    oin');\r"
expect "true"
expect ">"
send "var mortalContract = web3.eth.contract([{'constant':false,'inputs':[],'name':'kill','outputs':  [],'type':'function'},{'constant':false,'inputs':  [],'name':'cashOut','outputs':[],'type':'function'},{'inputs':[],'type':'constructor'}]);\r"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```